# Convert string to safe name for class

Tags: php, css

I have a dynamic menu that I need to convert into background images using CSS classes. I would like to convert the label into a safe class name for the css.

An example being:
- Convert string: 'Products & Sunflowers'
- Into a string that contains only a-z and 1-9. The above would be converted into a validate string that can be used as a class name eg: 'products_sunflowers'

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Could you spend more time defining the problem and give code examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use this:

```
preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($className)));
```

It will strip all but letters, convert to lower-case and remove all html tags.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `preg_replace`?

This will return 'ProductsSunflowers' for your above example.

```
preg_replace('#\W#g','',$className);
```

Comment: Technically if this is going to be truly CSS safe you need to also ensure that the classname doesn't start with a number. I'd just go with preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $className) to strip all but letters.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but if the goal is simply to create a CSS safe class name this would achieve that, it may not be the best or most exhaustive set of options for anything valid, but it's probably one of the simplest. I'm sure the regex could be made more complete if hyphens really matter. You should probably add this comment to the accepted answer too.

Answer (score 2):

### BEM-style clean_class php solution

Shamelessly interpolated from Drupal 7's [drupal_clean_css_identifier()](https://api.drupal.org/drupal_clean_css_identifier) and Drupal
10 [Html::cleanCssIdentifier()](https://api.drupal.org/Html::cleanCssIdentifier) functions.

```
/**
 * Convert any random string into a classname following conventions.
 * 
 * - preserve valid characters, numbers and unicode alphabet
 * - preserve already-formatted BEM-style classnames
 * - convert to lowercase
 *
 * @see http://getbem.com/
 */
function clean_class($identifier) {

  // Convert or strip certain special characters, by convention.
  $filter = [
    ' ' => '-',
    '__' => '__', // preserve BEM-style double-underscores
    '_' => '-', // otherwise, convert single underscore to dash
    '/' => '-',
    '[' => '-',
    ']' => '',
  ];
  $identifier = strtr($identifier, $filter);

  // Valid characters in a CSS identifier are:
  // - the hyphen (U+002D)
  // - a-z (U+0030 - U+0039)
  // - A-Z (U+0041 - U+005A)
  // - the underscore (U+005F)
  // - 0-9 (U+0061 - U+007A)
  // - ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher
  // We strip out any character not in the above list.
  $identifier = preg_replace('/[^\\x{002D}\\x{0030}-\\x{0039}\\x{0041}-\\x{005A}\\x{005F}\\x{0061}-\\x{007A}\\x{00A1}-\\x{FFFF}]/u', '', $identifier);

  // Convert everything to lower case.
  return strtolower($identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code to solve your problem, hope it helps

```
<?php
 # filename s.php
 $r ='@_+(\w)@';
$a='a_bf_csdfc__dasdf';
$b= ucfirst(preg_replace_callback(
    $r,
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[1]);
    },
        $a
    ));
echo $a,PHP_EOL;
echo $b,PHP_EOL;
```

> $ php -f s.php
>
> a_bf_csdfc__dasdf
>
> ABfCsdfcDasdf

Answer (score 0):

string: dome/some.thing-to.uppercase.words

result: DomeSomeThingToUppercaseWords

(add your pattern ofc)

```
var_dump(
    str_replace(
        ['/', '-', '.'], 
        '', 
        ucwords(
            $acceptContentType, '/-.'
        )
    )
);
```